# How to compile WinObjC project that uses MobileCoreServices

Tags: ios, uwp, winobjc

I'm trying to convert an IOS project with the WinObjC bridge but getting compilation error because the compiler can't find MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h

is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`MobileCoreServices` is not supported yet. An [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues/234) is already open and under review on github. Feel free to contribute